# Terraform - how to use exported attributes?

Tags: attributes, terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider

I'm learning terraform, in the example below the first section puts a VM and returns the id of that VM. The second section adds an extra disk to vm. I have to enter an id in the virtual_machine_id parameter, but I don't know how (cloudstack_instance.worker[$name].id not working).
Could someone have a hint?

```html
resource "cloudstack_instance" "worker" {
  for_each = {
    for name, machine in var.machines :
    name => machine
    if machine.node_type == "worker"
  }
  name = "${var.prefix}-${each.key}"
  service_offering = "K8S-RBD"
  network_id = var.network_id
  template = var.template_id
  zone = var.zone
  project = var.project_id
  expunge = true
  group = var.prefix
  keypair = var.keypair
  tags = {
    name = "Terraform-VM"
  }
}

resource "cloudstack_disk" "worker" {
  for_each = {
    for name, machine in var.machines :
    name => machine
    if machine.node_type == "worker"
  }
  name = "${var.prefix}-${each.key}"
  attach = "true"
  disk_offering = "Custom-RBD"
  size = 50
  virtual_machine_id = cloudstack_instance.worker[$name].id
  zone = var.zone
  project = var.project_id

  depends_on = [cloudstack_instance.worker]
}
```

Comment: `for_each` meta-argument documentation will assist here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your configuration it seems like your intent here is to declare one disk per virtual machine, with the disks each connected to their corresponding virtual machine.

That situation is a good use for [Chaining `for_each` Between Resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html#chaining-for_each-between-resources), which means to use an upstream resource directly as the `for_each` for a downstream one, and thus quite literally declare that the disks correlate with the VMs:

```
resource "cloudstack_disk" "worker" {
  for_each = cloudstack_instance.worker

  name               = "${var.prefix}-${each.key}"
  attach             = "true"
  disk_offering      = "Custom-RBD"
  size               = 50
  virtual_machine_id = each.value.id
  zone               = var.zone
  project            = var.project_id
}
```

Because the `cloudstack_instance` resource also has `for_each` declared, `cloudstack_instance.worker` evaluates to a map from instance keys to objects. That means that in the above example `each.value` refers to whatever element value in `cloudstack_instance.worker` corresponds with the key `each.key`.

I also removed the `depends_on` argument, because it's redundant: Terraform can already see that dependency because `for_each` contains a reference to that resource.

Comment: Works as expected, thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The output from `cloudstack_instance` can contain multiple elements. If there is more than one output it will need some logic. But for this use case let's say that the output from `cloudstack_instance` is 1 element.

Try this:

```
 virtual_machine_id = join(", ", cloudstack_instance.worker.*.id)
```

Comment: With single instance this solution work excelent :-)